# what is the procedure in SQL server to not execute anything(T SQL commands) but outputs the commands it would execute

Tags: t-sql

what is the procedure in SQL server to not execute anything(T SQL commands) but outputs the commands it would execute

Answer (score 2):

There isn't one unless you are using dynamic SQL where you'd use PRINT

You can see a stored proc definition but this won't show you any actual parameter values etc

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON`?